# grep for X or Y in unix?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

how can I capture all lines from a text file that begin with the character "X" or contain the word "foo"?

This works:

```
cat text | grep '^@'  # begins with @
```

but I tried:

```
cat text | grep '^@|[foo]'
```

and variations but cannot find the right syntax anywhere.  how can this be done?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your grep implementation isn't POSIX compliant, you can use egrep instead of grep:

```
egrep '^@|foo' text
```

Comment: With GNU grep, `grep -E` is an alternative

Answer (score 4):

```
cat text | grep '^@|foo'
```

does this. `[foo]` matches one character that's either an `f` or an `o`.

If you don't want to match parts of words like the `foo` in `foobar`, use word boundary anchors:

```
cat text | grep '^@|\bfoo\b'
```

Answer (score 2):

`contains the word "foo"` is: `(.*foo.*)` so your regex would become:

```
cat yourFilePath | grep -E '^@|(.*foo.*)'
```

Comment: +1 for grep -E, although shouldn't it be grep -E '(^@|foo)' ??

Comment: @TomMcClure Both will work for `grep` (ie. both will return the whole line containing `foo`). From the regular expressions point of view `/.*foo.*/` matches the whole line contaning `foo` while `/foo/` only matches the word `foo`. As I said there's no difference here unless you use `grep` with `-o` option.